# Get n last parts of a file path

Tags: python, path, filepath

I am looking for a way to extract the *n* last parts of a file path. The method should account for varying depths of the input file path (meaning that the method cannot use absolute indices, but rather should 'stop' until the most upper part is reached).

Example:

Depending on the 'input depth', `/dst/foo/bar/foobar.txt` should be reduced to:

```
/bar/
/foo/bar/
/dst/foo/bar/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute indices", is splitting the string a valid option?

Comment: It would mean that for the example path above you could not use a method that extracts the last 4 directories of the file path, since there are maximal 3 top directories.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
n_path = '/'.join(path.rsplit('/',n))
```

Comment: For me, this just returns the original file path, regardless of the input...

Comment: the second argument to rsplit specifies how many splits to do

Comment: I know, but I tried out for some example n's (-2,-1,0,1,2) and still get the original filepath